# Retrying a previously-run TFS build from powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I'm trying to programatically retry a previously-completed TFS build.  (Like you can do from VS by "Actions, Retry Build".)

My sample PS code below connects to TSF, grabs the build queue of a previous build by its ID, and attempts to set its retry status and save.  The save fails, saying that the build status needs to be "Completed."  Querying the status shows "Completed".

```
. ".\loadTfsAssemlies.ps1"

$tfsURL = "http://myServer:8080/tfs/myCollection"
$tpc = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsURL)
$bs = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$qb = $bs.getqueuedbuild(258498,"All")

$qb.retry()
$qb.save()

Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "Queued build 258498 on build controller blah blah can only be retried if the status is Completed. The status was Completed."
At line:1 char:1
+ $qb.save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : QueuedBuildUpdateException

 $qb.status
Completed
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  Or maybe know of a better way to retry a previous build?

Comment: Did you ever get past this? I just encountered it now. It's so bizarre, `"can only be retried if the status is Completed. The status was Completed."`

Answer (score 0):

After examining the difference between the request sent by `$qb.retry(); $qb.Save()` and right-clicking retry Visual Studio, I found that the calls need to be:

```
qb.Retry([Guid]::NewGuid(), "Completed")
qb.Save()
```

The `retryOption` needs to be passed in explicitly as `Completed`, or it'll default to `InProgress`.